# What are some syntax options for generators?

Tags: syntax, language-design, generators

Some programming languages allow you to create generators - lazily evaluated iterable objects that use a function to determine what the next item should be.

For example, Python allows:

```python
def f():
    x = 0
    while True:
        yield x
        x += 1
```

To generate an infinite list of numbers.

What other syntax options exist for generators?

Answer (score 4):

## Enumerators

Ruby uses this:

```ruby
Enumerator.new do |y|
  1.step do |num|
    y << num
  end
end
```

`Enumerator.new` just creates a new enumerator, taking a block, and passes a "yielder" object to the block, where you can call `y.yield` or `y <<` to yield a value. There is no special syntax for generators, just normal blocks.

Answer (score 2):

## Single-line Python-style

```python
(expr for x in iterable)
```

Basically a list comprehension but with parentheses instead of brackets. It's concise, but the downside is that it only allows one expression and you have to loop through an iterable (no `while` loops allowed).

Answer (score 2):

## Infinite recursive evaluation

For example, in Scala, for an infinite list of positive numbers:

```scala
lazy val numbers: LazyList[Int] = 1 #:: numbers.map(_ + 1)
```

`#::` prepends here. So we start with a list of `[1]`. Then recurse, add one to each, and prepend one again. Now it's `[1, 2]`. And so on.

A more elaborate example with fibonacci numbers:

```scala
val fib: LazyList[BigInt] = 0 #:: 1 #:: fib.zip(fib.tail).map(p => p._1 + p._2)
```

Or in Haskell:

```haskell
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```